# Why doesn't my "REM PrintBoxAt 1 1 25 80 2 " code work properly?

Tags: batch-file

I want to draw a neet little box in batch so that it looks good, I used this code for that:

```
Title Test
rem PrintBoxAt 1 1 25 80 2 
rem wait 200
PAUSE >NUL
EXIT
```

And the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf7cE.png).

I wanted to modify this code so that I could make the box bigger but the moment I do modify it like this:

```
Title Test
rem PrintBoxAt 1 1 26 81 2 
rem wait 200
PAUSE >NUL
EXIT
```

The box ends up breaking and I get [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4am2.png).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something that I'm missing? The help is much appreciated.

The Compiler that I'm using is "Advanced BAT to EXE Converter v4.2"

Comment: The fact that 80x25 works and 81x26 does not is a near certain indication this is a window size issue. Maybe it doesn't work with non standard sizes.

Comment: I see, thank you.
I've been busting my head for hours on something that I'm doing. I thought the box looked neet but if it ends up not working for what I'm doing then I'll try to find a work around.

Comment: The standard size in characters for a command window is 80x25 (80 characters wide by 25 high). You can change this in the command window properties. (More properly, it's 80 columns x 25 rows.)

Comment: Thank you Ken, I'll do this and see how I like it.

Comment: As nobody seems to have mentioned the elephant in the room, why does a line beginning with the standard internal commenting command `REM`, do anything other than act as an intended comment. There are of course two calves, _(smaller elephants)_, the first being what is `PrintBoxAt`? and the second, what on earth has the `Advanced BAT to EXE Converter v4.2` `Compiler`, to do with this question? In answer to your questions, "Am I doing something wrong?" and "Is there something that I'm missing?", I'd say, yes and yes, and both would expand as, written a clear, on topic, understandable question.

Comment: @Compo: that "Compiler" supports some [additional commands](https://www.battoexeconverter.com/#BatchFileCommands). It therefore evaluates and "translates" REM lines (usage of REM probably to not generate syntax errors when run outside the "Compiled" version).

Comment: @Losvaize: the site I mentioned above explicitly claims: `Batch file windows are 80 spaces in width and 25 spaces in height.`

Comment: @Stephan thank you, I read through that site but I didn't get as far as the "tips for using", that would have saved me lots of time. Thanks again.